# Login PHP and Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

Ok, basically i have a login.php which simply contains this form and connection from my mysql database: This is connected to my other file, login_success.php which contains the main body of the code to make my login function.

```
 <?php  
    include "header2.php";
    session_start();
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Login</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    #title {
    height: 200px;
    width: 600px; 
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-left: auto;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 35px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    }
    strong {
    font-size: 28px;
    font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    font-weight: bolder;
    color: #31CAF5;
    }
    #username, #password {
    width: 80%;
    height: 25px;
    padding: 5px;
    color: #999;
    background-color: #FFF;
    border: thin solid #CCC;
    padding-top: 10px;

    }
    #login, #reset {
    width: 70px;
    height: 30px;
    }
    #error {
    height: 20px;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 14px;
    background-color: #FF3C3C;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="title"> <strong>User Login</strong><br />
    <hr noshade="noshade" />
    <?php
    include ('db_connect.php');
    ?>
    <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="login_success.php">
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="5">
    <tr>
    <td width="16%"> <label for="username">Username</label></td>
    <td width="3%">:</td>
    <td width="81%"><input type="text" name="username" id="username" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td> <label for="password">Password</label></td>
    <td>:</td>
    <td><input type="password" name="password" id="password" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td> <input type="submit" name="login" id="login" value="Log In" />
    &nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="reset" name="reset" id="reset" value="Reset" /></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
    <?php
    //endif;
    include "footer.php" ?>
```

This code here is my file login_success. The idea is that when the user enters correct login credentials, it launches them into the session loggedIn. It is designed to allow passwords that are hashed on the database. However, for some reason, this lets any details through even if it is not login credentials saved on the database.

```
    <?php   
    session_start();
    //For cases where users are not logged in redirect back to login page.


        include "conn.php";
        include "header.php";

        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        $password = md5($password);

        //echo "password ".$password;
        //echo "username ".$username;

        $qry = "SELECT * FROM login WHERE username = '$username'";
        $userlogin = mysqli_query($_SESSION['conn'],$qry);
        $result = mysqli_fetch_array($userlogin);


        if (strcmp($result['password'], $password)==0) {
            $_SESSION["loggedIn"] = $username;
            $_SESSION["message"] = "Logged In Successfully.";
            header('Location: members.php');
        }
        else {
            $_SESSION["message"] = "Log In Failed";
            header('Location: login.php');
        }   



    if(!isset($_SESSION["loggedIn"])){
                    header("Location: index.php");
                    exit;
                }
        echo '<h1> Congratulations '.$_SESSION['loggedIn'].'</h1> <br> <h2>You successfully logged in!</h2><br>



             <h3><a href="logout.php">Logout</a> <a href="members.php">Continue</a></h3><br/><br/>';

    include ("footer.php");?>
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what your question is...

Comment: sorry. im exhausted and my english is terrible right now, basically. Using these two PHP files, my login form simply allows any credentials through, saying "Logged In Successfuly". However, i have set user accounts on my database. i.e. Username + Password that are the only accounts that should allow successful log in. My question is, why is this happening?

Comment: var_dump($result['password'], $password); Can you show the output of this?

Comment: where abouts should i put this sorry?

Comment: Right above your if-clause we discussed in the answer below.

Comment: Where exactly is it failing? And are you sure that your `$_SESSION["loggedIn"]` variable is not set?

Comment: @adamdunson If it outputs the success message, then it's sure...

Comment: sorry, im completely new to this, what output are you expecting shomz? apologies again

Comment: and yes, no matter what credentials i enter, it displays the success message: Congratulations true

You successfully logged in!

Comment: var_dump will output the values of your typed password and the one from the db, that's what I wanted to check first. Then, why are you starting the session twice?

Comment: so in my code it looks like this: 
`var_dump($result['password'], $password);
 if strcmp($result['password'], $password)==0 {
  $_SESSION["loggedIn"] = $username;
  $_SESSION["message"] = "Logged In Successfully.";
  header('Location: members.php');
 }`

Comment: yup, run the code and see the output... you can also put `die;` after the var_dump part.

Comment: in reply to your question, this was a group assignment which my group members have since given up on and attempted to fix their code, that's why im not really sure what's going on at all.

Comment: @Shomz Hm, not exactly what I meant. To clarify, (@ElliotSaunders) are you sure that your `$_SESSION["loggedIn"]` variable wasn't set from a previous (successful) attempt and hasn't been destroyed since?

Comment: @adamdunson But see the code, the variable check is done later and will cause a redirect... no success messages.

Comment: as far as i can see, there is no output from the var_dump

Comment: Can you paste the output, please?

Comment: where am i expecting this output to be displayed? ive never used var dump before and have no idea what im expecting

Comment: on the screen, where HTML used to be.

Comment: then it's not working as its just loading my page as normal

Comment: Put `die;` after that line, if will stop the rest of the script from executing.

Comment: i am sorry for my lack of knowledge, this is the first assignment i have done using php and mysql, before this it was just html & css (very basic aas well)

Comment: this is my code at the minute:

`var_dump die;($result['password'], $password);
 if strcmp($result['password'], $password)==0 {
  $_SESSION["loggedIn"] = $username;
  $_SESSION["message"] = "Logged In Successfully.";
  header('Location: members.php');
 }`

Comment: No worries, everyone here is trying to help.
No no, this: `var_dump ($result['password'], $password); die;`

Comment: ive done as you said, still nothing is showing

Comment: Are you calling the right script?

Comment: how should i be doing it? i feel like such an idiot here haha

Comment: check your URL; and are any other changes you make in the code visible? I gave you an idea in my answer - check what page you're on, what code is called for it and how your redirections work.

Comment: all ive been doing is making the changes that you've suggested and then attempting to log on as normal, i really have 0 knowledge of scripts or any of this stuff so sorry, im just trying to make sense of a login function left to me by my group.

Comment: Sorry, I can't help you further then. See my comments and answer for ideas about what could be wrong. There's no way we can teach you all the PHP here or do your homework, just help you with your problem.

Comment: ok well thank you for your help, apologies for wasting your time, im just stuck and have been for hours. the longer i go on, the more confused im getting but there we go. thanks again

Comment: No problem, sorry I couldn't help. Remember to use var_dump and die to debug your scripts (they must show something and stop the script execution).

Comment: @Shomz is there any way you could perhaps suggest the technique you would use in my situation as ive been left completely clueless. Thanks either way.

Comment: you should echo the $result['password'] also just before the strcmp statement condition to be sure of what's going on

Comment: I'd do exactly what I said in my previous comment - you need to figure out which scripts are running and which are not. Since you said there's no output from var_dump in the example I gave you, it means that script is not running.

Comment: @Sebas that's exactly what I was trying to tell him, just to use var_dump instead of echo...

Comment: plus there's a big issue. How come you get that congratulation message since anyway you should go through a header redirect either in case of success or failure? Also, `congratulation user true` seems weird to me, what kind of value are you passing to that script exactly? Please come back with a correct debug report.

Comment: Sorry but im completely lost, as i said, im completely new to all of this and dont understand half of the stuff thats being explained to me through no fault of yours. Thanks all the same guys!

Answer (score 0):

try this. i think strcmp function is the culprit here

```
<?php 
if (strcmp($result['password'], $password)==0) {
            $_SESSION["loggedIn"] = $username;
            $_SESSION["message"] = "Logged In Successfully.";
            header('Location: members.php');
        }
        else {
            $_SESSION["message"] = "Log In Failed";
            header('Location: login.php');
        }  
?>
```

should be

```
<?php 
if ($result == true) {
            $_SESSION["loggedIn"] = $result['username'];
            $_SESSION["message"] = "Logged In Successfully.";
            header('Location: members.php');
        }
        else {
            $_SESSION["message"] = "Log In Failed";
            header('Location: login.php');
        }  

?>
```